# Angular state provider, adding .html into url parameter is not working

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router

I am using ui-router `1.0.0-beta.1`, and my state looks like this:

```
.state('start.step2', {
            url: '/step2',
            template: startStep2,
            reloadOnSearch: false,
            parent: 'start'
        })
```

so url for this state is `/start/step2`

now due to backend reason, I need to change it to `/start/step2.html`, so I changed the url parameter to be

```
.state('start.step2', {
                url: '/step2.html',
                template: startStep2,
                reloadOnSearch: false,
                parent: 'start'
            })
```

But the page would show cannot get `/start/step2.html` error. So how to add .html into url?

thanks

Comment: now due to backend? can you be more specific here

Answer (score 0):

You have to set `.htaccess` file and set rules for redirecting your requests to the angular routes for proper working . Else your server will look for files in the actual routes .

sample `.htaccess` file

```
 RewriteEngine on
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -s [OR]
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l [OR]
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
 RewriteRule ^.*$ - [NC,L]

 RewriteRule ^(.*) /index.html [NC,L]
```